# How to display error message

Tags: java

Could someone tell me how to put an error message in to the following code? If the user enters a number that is not between 0 and 12, how do I output "Invalid entry".

The program at the moment works fine and if an invalid character is entered the user is allowed to try again.

```
int hours;
do {                
    System.out.print("Enter hours: ");
    hours = myscanner.nextInt();
} while (hours < 0 || hours > 12);
```

Comment: `if(....) System.out.println("Error");` ?

Comment: If the user enters a number that is not between 0 and 12, then the loop continues cycling. Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: shouldn't this condition be inverted: hours < 0 || hours > 12 ?

Comment: His condition is fine: anything below 0 or above 12 is invalid.

Comment: He said in his question that the condition is fine. He just wants an extra message when they enter something invalid

Comment: @Andrei Nicusan Yes, because it keeps asking them until they enter a correct digit.

Comment: Ok, then they will keep getting the "Enter hours: " message until they input something right. At least you can change it to "Enter hours (0-12): "

Answer (score 2):

I would use an "infinite" while loop and break out of it when the hours figure is valid. `while(true) { ... }` is idiomatic Java.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int hours;
while (true) {                
    System.out.print("Enter hours: ");
    hours = scanner.nextInt();
    if (hours >= 0 && hours <= 12) {
        break;
    }
    System.err.println("Invalid entry (should be 0-12)");
}
```

Comment: It would also be nice to catch the very likely exception "InputTypeMismatch", but it's not part of the question...

Answer (score 0):

```
int hours;
boolean valid;
do {                
    System.out.print("Enter hours: ");
    hours = myscanner.nextInt();
    valid = (hours >= 0 && hours <= 12);
    if (!valid)
        System.out.println("Invalid entry");
} while (!valid);
```

NOTE: I've added a variable, because otherwise, you'd have duplicate condition there
NOTE2: I've also reverted the condition because I don't like if booleans are referring to negative condition(I prefer valid over invalid)

Comment: Cruncher: I made a few typos when I was writing it so there was a time, when there was complete gibberish in the answer

Comment: Thanks for your help. The error message now works but it doesn't loop back to allow for re-entry of a digit.

Comment: @HungryHenno It should

Comment: I don't know why but it won't work but I'm going to use the boolean method mentioned above. It works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
int hours;
do {                
    System.out.print("Enter hours: ");
    hours = myscanner.nextInt();
    if (hours < 0 || hours > 12) System.out.println("Please insert a valid entry");
} while (hours < 0 || hours > 12);
```

Comment: If you have the if statement, no reason to check the condition twice. Change it to a while(true) and break when you get a good input maybe? p.s I don't think this is worth a downvote. Can the voter explain?

Comment: @Cruncher of course, there's already the aetheria proposition for that. My (obvious) solution is just for not upset the initial code.

Comment: @mauretto My comment was 7 minutes before aetheria's answer :)

Comment: @Cruncher LOOOL btw my intent was really to not upset his reasoning! ;)